# We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer:

Tags: support, questions, answers

> We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer: please explain why you're recommending it as a solution. Answers that don't explain anything will be deleted. See Good Subjective, Bad Subjective for more information.

It appears at the bottom of certain questions; but not all. What determines whethere it does , or not ? .

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186087/a-better-insufficient-explanation-post-notice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a post notice that moderators can apply, they were originally created for Skeptics (the "citation needed" notice) and for some of the more subjective sites where such short and lazy answers were a significant problem. But they are occasionally used on other sites as well, though not all that much because they are a mod-only feature.